# Isomorphism for group with 2 generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that a map $\rho: G \rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphism. Here $G=\langle x,y|y^{-1}xy=x^2\rangle$ and $x$ and $y$ are sent to specific matricies say $x$ to $A$ and $y$ to $B$ and these matricies have some "special" properties. I am stuck on proving that the map is one to one and a homomorphism. For injectivity, I am choosing setting two elements in $G$  written in their reduced form in terms of $x,y$. But this element can be infinitely long and I cannot condense it in the form $x^ly^m$. Hence I don't know how to proceed for injectivity and homomorphism

Comment: There are no "infinitely long" words in $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: @whacka: Could please give an example? I wasnt able to condense the word that I chose.

Comment: An example of what? I said there are **not** any infinitely long words. By definition, $\langle x,y\rangle$ can only contain finite words in $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, your group $G$ here is the [Baumslag-Solitar group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag-Solitar_group)
$B(2,1)$. This group is metabelian and has a faithful linear representation into $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$, given by
$$
x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
y\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 \cr
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is this the map $\rho$ you are considering ? The injectivity is discussed also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112320/kernel-of-linear-representation-of-baumslag-solitar-group).

Comment: Yes, indeed! Thank you. Out of curiosity, does there exist a direct proof for injectivity and homomorphism because we can clearly see some patterns in the images of elements $x^m$ and $y^n$

Comment: Homomorphism follows from the definition. We have, say, $\rho(x^2y)=\rho(x)\rho(x)\rho(y)$.